# How to fix apt install libgtk-3-dev:i386 Depends ... but it is not going to be installed problems

Tags: ubuntu, gtk3, apt, tauri

I run the following commands on github ubuntu-latest(ubuntu 22.04) with some error recently.

```yaml
      - name: 'Setup for linux'
        if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'
        run: |
          # https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts
          # https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252062/how-to-install-libncurses-so-5-in-ubuntu-20-04
          # https://askubuntu.com/questions/522372/installing-32-bit-libraries-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit
          # sudo add-apt-repository universe
          sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
          sudo apt update
          # sudo apt upgrade
          # install both 32-bit and 64-bit prerequisites of tauri
          # libayatana-appindicator3-dev is the successor of libappindicator3-dev and 64-bit only
          # https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/prerequisites/#setting-up-linux
          # https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md
          echo install tools for 32-bit support ...
          sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
          sudo apt update
          # sudo apt upgrade
          sudo apt install -y --allow-downgrades \
            gcc-multilib \
            g++-multilib
          echo install 32-bit dependences ...
          sudo apt update
          # sudo apt upgrade
          sudo apt install -y --allow-downgrades \
            libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:i386 \
            libssl-dev:i386 \
            libgtk-3-dev:i386 \
            librsvg2-dev:i386 || echo "install 32-bit dependences failed! Check the logs for details."
          echo install dependences ...
          sudo apt install -y --allow-downgrades \
            libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            libgtk-3-dev \
            librsvg2-dev \
            libayatana-appindicator3-dev
```

The full error logs.

```
Run # https://ubuntu.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
......
install 32-bit dependences ...

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
52 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-jammy.list
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy main
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ jammy main
# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ jammy main
apt-cache policy ...
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
     2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     2.36.0-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
libssl-dev:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9
  Version table:
     3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     3.0.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
libgtk-3-dev:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.24.33-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     3.24.33-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
     3.24.33-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
librsvg2-dev:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.52.5+dfsg-3
  Version table:
     2.52.5+dfsg-3 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 20
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 20
Investigating (0) libgtk-3-dev:i386 < none -> 3.24.33-1ubuntu2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libgtk-3-dev:i386 Depends on libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 < none @un H > (>= 2.40.0)
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to libgtk-3-dev:i386 10000
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to libgtk-3-dev:i386 10000
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to libgtk-3-dev:i386 10000
Broken libgtk-3-dev:i386 Depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386 < none @un H > (>= 2.40.0)
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to libgtk-3-dev:i386 10000
Investigating (0) librsvg2-dev:i386 < none -> 2.52.5+dfsg-3 @un puN Ib >
Broken librsvg2-dev:i386 Depends on libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 < none @un H > (>= 2.23.5-2)
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to librsvg2-dev:i386 9999
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to librsvg2-dev:i386 9999
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to librsvg2-dev:i386 9999
Broken librsvg2-dev:i386 Depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386 < none @un H > (>= 2.23.5-2)
  Considering libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386 0 as a solution to librsvg2-dev:i386 9999
Investigating (0) libc6:i386 < none -> 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libc6:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH >
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libc6:i386 904
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libc6:i386 904
Investigating (0) libicu70:i386 < none -> 70.1-2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libicu70:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 7)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libicu70:i386 21
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libicu70:i386 21
Broken libicu70:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 5.2)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libicu70:i386 21
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libicu70:i386 21
Investigating (0) libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 < none -> 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 7)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 4
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 4
Broken libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 12)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 4
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 4
Investigating (0) librsvg2-2:i386 < none -> 2.52.5+dfsg-3 @un puN Ib >
Broken librsvg2-2:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 4.2)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to librsvg2-2:i386 4
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to librsvg2-2:i386 4
Investigating (0) libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 < none -> 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 7)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 2
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 2
Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 11)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 2
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 2
Investigating (0) libegl-mesa0:i386 < none -> 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libegl-mesa0:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 4.2)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libegl-mesa0:i386 1
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libegl-mesa0:i386 1
Investigating (0) libwoff1:i386 < none -> 1.0.2-1build4 @un puN Ib >
Broken libwoff1:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.0)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libwoff1:i386 1
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libwoff1:i386 1
Broken libwoff1:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 11)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libwoff1:i386 1
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libwoff1:i386 1
Investigating (0) libllvm15:i386 < none -> 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libllvm15:i386 Depends on libatomic1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 4.8)
  Considering libatomic1:i386 0 as a solution to libllvm15:i386 1
  Considering libatomic1:i386 0 as a solution to libllvm15:i386 1
Broken libllvm15:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 4.2)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libllvm15:i386 1
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libllvm15:i386 1
Broken libllvm15:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 12)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libllvm15:i386 1
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libllvm15:i386 1
Investigating (0) gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 < none -> 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 @un puN Ib >
Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.0)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 1
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 1
Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 5)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 1
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 1
Investigating (0) libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 < none -> 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 4.2)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 1
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 1
Broken libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 11)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 1
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 1
Investigating (0) libenchant-2-2:i386 < none -> 2.3.2-1ubuntu2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libenchant-2-2:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.0)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libenchant-2-2:i386 1
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libenchant-2-2:i386 1
Broken libenchant-2-2:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 5.2)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libenchant-2-2:i386 1
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libenchant-2-2:i386 1
Investigating (0) libpcrecpp0v5:i386 < none -> 2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libpcrecpp0v5:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.0)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libpcrecpp0v5:i386 0
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libpcrecpp0v5:i386 0
Broken libpcrecpp0v5:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 5.2)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libpcrecpp0v5:i386 0
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libpcrecpp0v5:i386 0
Investigating (0) libaspell15:i386 < none -> 0.60.8-4build1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libaspell15:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 11)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libaspell15:i386 0
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libaspell15:i386 0
Investigating (0) libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 < none -> 1.11.1+dfsg.1-3ubuntu3 @un puN Ib >
Broken libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.0)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 0
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 0
Broken libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 5.2)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 0
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 0
Investigating (0) libvpx7:i386 < none -> 1.11.0-2ubuntu2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libvpx7:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 4.2)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libvpx7:i386 0
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libvpx7:i386 0
Investigating (0) libproxy1v5:i386 < none -> 0.4.17-2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libproxy1v5:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.0)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libproxy1v5:i386 0
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libproxy1v5:i386 0
Broken libproxy1v5:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 11)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libproxy1v5:i386 0
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libproxy1v5:i386 0
Investigating (0) libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 < none -> 1.7.0-4build1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 Depends on libgcc-s1:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.0)
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 0
  Considering libgcc-s1:i386 1 as a solution to libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 0
Broken libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 11)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 0
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 0
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
Investigating (0) libcaca0:i386 < none -> 0.99.beta19-2.2ubuntu4 @un puN Ib >
Broken libcaca0:i386 Depends on libstdc++6:i386 < none | 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 4.1.1)
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libcaca0:i386 0
  Considering libstdc++6:i386 0 as a solution to libcaca0:i386 0
Done
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                                  Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5) but it is not going to be installed
 libaspell15:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libcaca0:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libegl-mesa0:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libenchant-2-2:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk-3-dev:i386 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not installable or
                              libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not installable
 libhunspell-1.7-0:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
 libicu70:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 12) but it is not going to be installed
 libllvm15:i386 : Depends: libatomic1:i386 (>= 4.8) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 12) but it is not going to be installed
 libpcrecpp0v5:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libproxy1v5:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
 librsvg2-2:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not going to be installed
 librsvg2-dev:i386 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev:i386 (>= 2.23.5-2) but it is not installable or
                              libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386 (>= 2.23.5-2) but it is not installable
 libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libvpx7:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
 libwoff1:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
install 32-bit dependences failed! Check the logs for details.
```

And I added some debug info in the apt commands, but I still could not find the root issues why the installation failed and the solutions how to fix it.